# How can I repair a Goot PX-201 soldering iron which was exposed to too high AC supply voltage?

Tags: repair

I had a stupidity to plug 100V Japan version of Goot PX-201 soldering iron to 220V. It heated up for a second, but that was it, it no longer heats up.

I tried to disassemble it, hoping to find a simple fuse, but failed to find the failing / burned component.

Any chance it could be diagnosed and repaired at home using multimeter? Or shall I just give up, and look for a new one?

Here is how it looks like under the cover:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you measured resistance across the heater element (with at least 1 leg disconnected)?

Comment: With both legs connected it's 50oms, but will try. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no obvious burn marks, the electronic control circuit most likely got fried.  Whatever is doing the voltage regulation from the input AC to the low voltage the control circuit needs got severely abused.

Maybe you can read part number off the chips and find replacements, but if not this unit is toast.  Ditch it and move on.

Answer (score 1):

[These guys](http://images.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http://fotkidepo.ru/photo/229919/20231FxODb52R03/838951w.jpg&imgrefurl=http://radiokot.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f%3D33%26t%3D101704&h=313&w=675&tbnid=_SCEQ3s3Q7JA5M:&tbnh=90&tbnw=194&docid=992RSBJB_SSI8M&usg=__TQsH8KIzAmNFxFe_zc8dK_dZX_A=&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLrOvg-ZLKAhXJ_SwKHSBkDBIQ9QEIOjAE) have a schematic of the Goot PX201.
[image]

It looks like the only IC in the thing is pretty much unprotected against high voltage.  [The uC1701c](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjlxIyn_JLKAhUEqHIKHYlYChwQFgg0MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdatasheet.octopart.com%2FUPC1701C-NEC-datasheet-101908.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHA9s11VekPVWUekHg73cdbDsRtmA&bvm=bv.110151844,d.bGg&cad=rja) seems to be a triac controller.  It works when given 8Volts from source to ground (pins 5 and 7,) and the schematic shows it only having a capacitor in series to drop the line voltage.

So, over voltage probably killed the uC1701.

---

Exercise caution when seraching for images of the goot PX201 schematic.  I have no idea what that woman has to do with a soldering iron, but the image was definitely NSFW.